# Link in the same column five different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, case

I'm making a query to link the results of five tables depend one value, but I can't get the result that I need, because the result give me 5 diferent columns (CodigoProyecto), I need to link these in only one, the query:

```
SELECT     TES_CarteraPrevisiones.CodigoEmpresa, TES_CarteraPrevisiones.IdDelegacion, TES_CarteraPrevisiones.IdPrevision, TES_CarteraPrevisiones.CodigoTipoPrevision, 
                      TES_CarteraPrevisiones.TipoPrevision, TES_CarteraPrevisiones.EjercicioDocumento, TES_CarteraPrevisiones.SerieDocumento, 
                      TES_CarteraPrevisiones.NumeroDocumento, TES_CarteraPrevisiones.FechaDocumento, TES_CarteraPrevisiones.NumeroOrdenEfecto, 
                      TES_CarteraPrevisiones.Comentario, TES_CarteraPrevisiones.CodigoClienteProveedor, TES_CarteraPrevisiones.CodigoCuenta, 
                      TES_CarteraPrevisiones.Contrapartida, TES_CarteraPrevisiones.CodigoCanal, TES_CarteraPrevisiones.CodigoTipoEfecto, TES_CarteraPrevisiones.ClaseEfecto, 
                      TES_CarteraPrevisiones.FechaOperacion, TES_CarteraPrevisiones.FechaValor, TES_CarteraPrevisiones.ImporteEfecto, TES_CarteraPrevisiones.Bloqueo, 
                      TES_CarteraPrevisiones.MovPosicionOrigen, TES_CarteraPrevisiones.FechaProceso, TES_CarteraPrevisiones.UsuarioProceso, TES_CarteraPrevisiones.Prevision, 
                      TES_CarteraPrevisiones.TipoEfecto, TES_CarteraPrevisiones.Comentarios, 
                      CASE WHEN TES_CarteraPrevisiones.Prevision = 'C' THEN Clientes.Razonsocial ELSE Proveedores.RazonSocial END AS RazonSocial,
                      CASE WHEN TES_CarteraPrevisiones.Prevision = 'C' THEN TES_CarteraPrevisiones.ImporteEfecto ELSE 0.00 END AS ImporteCobros, 
                      CASE WHEN TES_CarteraPrevisiones.Prevision = 'P' THEN TES_CarteraPrevisiones.ImporteEfecto ELSE 0.00 END AS ImportePagos,
                      CASE WHEN TES_CarteraPrevisiones.CodigoTipoPrevision = 1 THEN ResumenCliente.CodigoProyecto ELSE NULL END AS CodigoProyecto,
                      CASE WHEN TES_CarteraPrevisiones.CodigoTipoPrevision = 2 THEN ResumenProveedor.CodigoProyecto ELSE NULL END AS CodigoProyecto,
                      CASE WHEN TES_CarteraPrevisiones.CodigoTipoPrevision = 9 THEN TES_Presupuestos.Comentario ELSE NULL END AS CodigoProyecto,
                      CASE WHEN TES_CarteraPrevisiones.CodigoTipoPrevision = 11 THEN CabeceraPedidoCliente.CodigoProyecto ELSE NULL END AS CodigoProyecto,
                      CASE WHEN TES_CarteraPrevisiones.CodigoTipoPrevision = 12 THEN CabeceraPedidoProveedor.CodigoProyecto ELSE NULL END AS CodigoProyecto
FROM         TES_CarteraPrevisiones LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      Proveedores ON TES_CarteraPrevisiones.CodigoEmpresa = Proveedores.CodigoEmpresa AND 
                      TES_CarteraPrevisiones.CodigoClienteProveedor = Proveedores.CodigoProveedor AND TES_CarteraPrevisiones.Prevision = 'P' LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      Clientes ON TES_CarteraPrevisiones.CodigoEmpresa = Clientes.CodigoEmpresa AND TES_CarteraPrevisiones.CodigoClienteProveedor = Clientes.CodigoCliente AND 
                      TES_CarteraPrevisiones.Prevision = 'C'
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN ResumenCliente on ResumenCliente.CodigoEmpresa=TES_CarteraPrevisiones.CodigoEmpresa 
and ResumenCliente.EjercicioFactura=TES_CarteraPrevisiones.EjercicioDocumento 
and ResumenCliente.SerieFactura=TES_CarteraPrevisiones.SerieDocumento
and ResumenCliente.NumeroFactura=TES_CarteraPrevisiones.NumeroDocumento

LEFT OUTER JOIN ResumenProveedor on ResumenProveedor.CodigoEmpresa=TES_CarteraPrevisiones.CodigoEmpresa 
and ResumenProveedor.EjercicioFactura=TES_CarteraPrevisiones.EjercicioDocumento 
and ResumenProveedor.SerieFactura=TES_CarteraPrevisiones.SerieDocumento
and ResumenProveedor.NumeroFactura=TES_CarteraPrevisiones.NumeroDocumento

LEFT OUTER JOIN TES_Presupuestos on TES_Presupuestos.CodigoEmpresa=TES_CarteraPrevisiones.CodigoEmpresa 
and TES_Presupuestos.EjercicioPresupuesto=TES_CarteraPrevisiones.EjercicioDocumento 
and TES_Presupuestos.SeriePresupuesto=TES_CarteraPrevisiones.SerieDocumento
and TES_Presupuestos.NumeroPresupuesto=TES_CarteraPrevisiones.NumeroDocumento

LEFT OUTER JOIN CabeceraPedidoCliente on CabeceraPedidoCliente.CodigoEmpresa=TES_CarteraPrevisiones.CodigoEmpresa 
and CabeceraPedidoCliente.EjercicioPedido=TES_CarteraPrevisiones.EjercicioDocumento 
and CabeceraPedidoCliente.SeriePedido=TES_CarteraPrevisiones.SerieDocumento
and CabeceraPedidoCliente.NumeroPedido=TES_CarteraPrevisiones.NumeroDocumento

LEFT OUTER JOIN CabeceraPedidoProveedor on CabeceraPedidoProveedor.CodigoEmpresa=TES_CarteraPrevisiones.CodigoEmpresa 
and CabeceraPedidoProveedor.EjercicioPedido=TES_CarteraPrevisiones.EjercicioDocumento 
and CabeceraPedidoProveedor.SeriePedido=TES_CarteraPrevisiones.SerieDocumento
and CabeceraPedidoProveedor.NumeroPedido=TES_CarteraPrevisiones.NumeroDocumento

ORDER BY CodigoProyecto, TES_CarteraPrevisiones.TipoPrevision, TES_CarteraPrevisiones.EjercicioDocumento, TES_CarteraPrevisiones.SerieDocumento, TES_CarteraPrevisiones.NumeroDocumento, TES_CarteraPrevisiones.CodigoClienteProveedor
```

I do not know if I have managed to explain myself well..

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Minimize the problem. Two or three tables, fewer columns, shorter names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have more than one item in a case statement, just add as many `WHEN` clauses as you need.

```
CASE 
  WHEN TES_CarteraPrevisiones.CodigoTipoPrevision = 1 THEN ResumenCliente.CodigoProyecto 
  WHEN TES_CarteraPrevisiones.CodigoTipoPrevision = 2 THEN ResumenProveedor.CodigoProyecto
  WHEN TES_CarteraPrevisiones.CodigoTipoPrevision = 9 THEN TES_Presupuestos.Comentario
  WHEN TES_CarteraPrevisiones.CodigoTipoPrevision = 11 THEN CabeceraPedidoCliente.CodigoProyecto 
  WHEN TES_CarteraPrevisiones.CodigoTipoPrevision = 12 THEN CabeceraPedidoProveedor.CodigoProyecto 
  ELSE NULL 
END AS CodigoProyecto
```

Comment: Why not simplify the `case` expression as `case TES_CarteraPrevisiones.CodigoTipoPrevision  when 1 then ... when 2 then ... end`, to save some typing?

Comment: @jarlh -- because I believe typing is less important than maintainability and I've always found this was is much easier to maintain.